# Query Access for Group, Group Member, RecordType, UserRole

Tags: query, permissions, record-type, public-group

What permissions / controls, if any, are there to control whether a user can query group, group member, recordtype, or user role?

If they are not a member of a group (role, group), can they query all groups or roles?

If they are not a top-level role, can they query all UserRoles?

If they are not assigned a record type, can they query all record types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are not a member of a group (role, group), can they query all groups or roles? Yes.

If they are not a top-level role, can they query all UserRoles? Yes.

If they are not assigned a record type, can they query all record types? Yes. However, they cannot query records of this record type if they are not assigned, they can only query the record types themselves.